# Flutter Error Undefined class 'RenderContext'

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart, intellij-idea

I am having trouble running a Flutter project that was previously working fine with a different person. Specifically, I am encountering an error related to the `RenderContext` class. The error message I am seeing is: 'Undefined class 'RenderContext' (undefined_class at [path to my file]:[line number]).'

I am using IntelliJ as my environment for this project, and this is my first time using IntelliJ with Flutter. I have tried to use Android Studio to solve this problem.

However, I am still encountering the same error message related to RenderContext. I suspect that there may be a configuration or setup step in IntelliJ that I may have missed.

Can you please offer any suggestions or guidance on how to resolve this issue and get my project running again in IntelliJ? Thank you for your assistance!

**The Error**

Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...

```
  - ../../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/universal_html- 
  2.2.2/lib/src/html/dom/element_subclasses.dart:2752:30: Error: The argument type 
'String?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Object' because 'String?' is nullable and 'Object' isn't.
  'Object' is from 'dart:core'.
   final parsed = css.parse(text);
                         ^
  - lib/view/screens/location/widget/web_landing_page.dart:268:51: Error: 'RenderContext' isn't a type.
                      onLinkTap: (String url, RenderContext context, Map<String, String> attributes, element) {
                                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  - lib/view/screens/location/widget/web_landing_page.dart:268:38: Error: The argument type 'Null Function(String, invalid-type, Map<String, String>, 
    dynamic)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function(String, Map<String, String>, Element)'.
   'Map' is from 'dart:core'.
   'Element' is from 'package:html/dom.dart' ('../../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/html-0.15.4/lib/dom.dart').
                      onLinkTap: (String url, RenderContext context, Map<String, String> attributes, element) {
                                 ^
  - lib/view/screens/html/html_viewer_screen.dart:111:57: Error: 'RenderContext' isn't a type.
                            onLinkTap: (String url, RenderContext context,
                                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  - lib/view/screens/html/html_viewer_screen.dart:108:31: Error: The method 'SelectableHtml' isn't defined for the class '_HtmlViewerScreenState'.

    -'_HtmlViewerScreenState' is from 'package:alqalaf/view/screens/html/html_viewer_screen.dart' ('lib/view/screens/html/html_viewer_screen.dart').

  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'SelectableHtml'.
                        : SelectableHtml(
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception


  FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

[image: Run Errors]

[image: Dart Analysis]

Comment: Does the project works if you run through the command line outside of the IDE? E.g:  run 'assembleDebug' gradle task from the terminal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably because html package version, the newer version has removed RenderContext, you can try removing the ^ symbol in the pubspec.yaml file.

example:
`flutter_html: ^3.0.0-alpha.6 to flutter_html: 3.0.0-alpha.6`

Comment: Thank you so much for your help in resolving that issue. I can't believe that was the problem, especially since the project had been upgraded. Thank you once again.

Answer (score 0):

```
flutter_html: ^3.0.0-alpha.5
```

just remove this ^ in your `pubspec.yml`